# why I use "local_repository" in a .bzl file， then it tell me name 'local_repository' is not defined?

Tags: bazel

I wanna build envoy via bazel，i mannual download some package in my pc, then I change http_archive to local_repository, but it tell me name 'local_repository' is not defined. Did local_repository need any load action?

local_repository can be used in WORKSPACE,but can not in my .bzl file

```
WORKSPACE:
workspace(name = "envoy")
load("//bazel:api_repositories.bzl", "envoy_api_dependencies")
envoy_api_dependencies()
load("//bazel:repositories.bzl", "GO_VERSION", "envoy_dependencies")
load("//bazel:cc_configure.bzl", "cc_configure")
envoy_dependencies()
`repositories.bzl`:
local_repository(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    path = "/home/user/com_google_protobuf",
)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`local_repository` is a [workspace rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#workspace-rules) so I think it's not available outside of the `WORKSPACE` file.

If you want to call `local_repository` from a `.bzl` file you can define a function in there, using `native`, and call it from `WORKSPACE`, e.g.:

```py
# repositories.bzl
def deps():
  native.local_repository(
    name = "com_google_protobuf",
    path = "/home/user/com_google_protobuf",
  )
```

```py
# WORKSPACE
load("//:repositories.bzl", "deps")

deps()
```

I've seen this pattern, for example, in the [grpc](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/v1.23.0/WORKSPACE) project.

Answer (score 2):

In a `.bzl` file, you have to use `native.local_repository` instead of just `local_repository`.

All symbols in `.bzl` files are expected to be defined in Starlark, but `local_repository` is a special rule that is defined natively within Bazel.